# How to draw canvas when image change

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have a canvas and a image slide with thumbnail

I want the canvas to redraw every time the image change

For example: When i click the thumbnail, canvas will draw the image that i chose

=> I try to trigger the image onload and then draw canvas but it seems like i mess up something, canvas will draw the previous image not the current one

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: 'fade',
    controlsContainer: '.flexslider',
    slideshow: false
  });
  window.addEventListener('load', draw);
  async function draw() {
    let canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    let url = $(".flex-active-slide img").attr("src");
    let img = new Image();
    await new Promise(r => img.onload = r, img.src = url);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }
  $(".flex-control-nav li a").on('click', function() {
    draw();
  });
});
```

```css
/* #########################################################

HOW TO CREATE A RESPONSIVE IMAGE SLIDER [TUTORIAL]

"How to create a Responsive Image Slider [Tutorial]" was specially made for DesignModo by our friend Valeriu Timbuc.

Links:
http://vtimbuc.net
http://designmodo.com
http://vladimirkudinov.com

######################################################### */


/* Browser Resets */

.flex-container a:active,
.flexslider a:active,
.flex-container a:focus,
.flexslider a:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.slides,
.flex-control-nav,
.flex-direction-nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.flexslider a img {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

.flexslider {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Hide the slides before the JS is loaded. Avoids image jumping */

.flexslider .slides>li {
  display: none;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flexslider .slides img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}


/* Clearfix for the .slides element */

.slides:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}

html[xmlns] .slides {
  display: block;
}

* html .slides {
  height: 1%;
}


/* Theme Styles */

.flexslider {
  position: relative;
  zoom: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}


/* Edit it if you want */

.flex-container {
  min-width: 150px;
  max-width: 960px;
}

.flexslider .slides {
  zoom: 1;
}


/* Direction Nav */

.flex-direction-nav a {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: -17px 0 0 0;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  top: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: #82d344;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#82d344), to(#51af34));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #82d344, #51af34);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #82d344, #51af34);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #82d344, #51af34);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #82d344, #51af34);
}

.flex-direction-nav a:before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 9px;
  height: 13px;
  top: 11px;
  left: 11px;
  background: url(http://designmodo.com/demo/responsiveslider/img/arrows.png) no-repeat;
}

.flex-direction-nav a:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 35px;
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
  right: -5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
  left: -5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-next:before {
  background-position: -9px 0;
  left: 15px;
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev:before {
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-next:after {
  right: 0;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid #31611e;
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev:after {
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid #31611e;
}


/* Control Nav */

.flexslider .flex-control-nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: -40px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 0 -10px;
}

.flex-control-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
}

.flex-control-paging li a {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin: 0 3px;
  background-color: #b6b6b6 \9;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #b6b6b6;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #b6b6b6;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #b6b6b6;
}

.flex-control-paging li a.flex-active {
  background-color: #82d344;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#82d344), to(#51af34));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #82d344, #51af34);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #82d344, #51af34);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #82d344, #51af34);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #82d344, #51af34);
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}


/* Captions */

.flexslider .slides p {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 100px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #222222;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://designmodo.com/demo/responsiveslider/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-container" style="margin-bottom:50px;">
  <div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li class="">
        <img src="http://designmodo.com/demo/responsiveslider/img/slide1.jpg" />
      </li>

      <li>
        <img src="http://designmodo.com/demo/responsiveslider/img/slide2.jpg" />
      </li>

      <li>
        <img src="http://designmodo.com/demo/responsiveslider/img/slide3.jpg" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem on `$(".flex-control-nav li a")` javascript part.

The problem is that `.flex-control-nav li a` selectors are not existed so you are not able to define the event listeners for that one.

It is because on the code snippet, you are using jquery `flexslider` to make the sliders and that control navs are created dynamically by jquery `flexslider.

jquery `flexslider` provides events `after` when is fired after each slider animation completes, so you can call `draw` function on `after` event as follows.

You can find more details related to `after` event [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/FlexSlider/wiki/FlexSlider-Properties).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: 'fade',
    controlsContainer: '.flexslider',
    slideshow: false,
    after: function () {
      draw();
    }
  });
  window.addEventListener('load', draw);
  async function draw() {
    let canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    let url = $(".flex-active-slide img").attr("src");
    let img = new Image();
    await new Promise(r => img.onload = r, img.src = url);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }
});
```

```css
/* #########################################################

HOW TO CREATE A RESPONSIVE IMAGE SLIDER [TUTORIAL]

"How to create a Responsive Image Slider [Tutorial]" was specially made for DesignModo by our friend Valeriu Timbuc.

Links:
http://vtimbuc.net
http://designmodo.com
http://vladimirkudinov.com

######################################################### */


/* Browser Resets */

.flex-container a:active,
.flexslider a:active,
.flex-container a:focus,
.flexslider a:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.slides,
.flex-control-nav,
.flex-direction-nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.flexslider a img {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

.flexslider {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Hide the slides before the JS is loaded. Avoids image jumping */

.flexslider .slides>li {
  display: none;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flexslider .slides img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}


/* Clearfix for the .slides element */

.slides:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}

html[xmlns] .slides {
  display: block;
}

* html .slides {
  height: 1%;
}


/* Theme Styles */

.flexslider {
  position: relative;
  zoom: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}


/* Edit it if you want */

.flex-container {
  min-width: 150px;
  max-width: 960px;
}

.flexslider .slides {
  zoom: 1;
}


/* Direction Nav */

.flex-direction-nav a {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: -17px 0 0 0;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  top: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: #82d344;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#82d344), to(#51af34));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #82d344, #51af34);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #82d344, #51af34);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #82d344, #51af34);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #82d344, #51af34);
}

.flex-direction-nav a:before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 9px;
  height: 13px;
  top: 11px;
  left: 11px;
  background: url(http://designmodo.com/demo/responsiveslider/img/arrows.png) no-repeat;
}

.flex-direction-nav a:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 35px;
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
  right: -5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
  left: -5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-next:before {
  background-position: -9px 0;
  left: 15px;
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev:before {
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-next:after {
  right: 0;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid #31611e;
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev:after {
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid #31611e;
}


/* Control Nav */

.flexslider .flex-control-nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: -40px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 0 -10px;
}

.flex-control-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
}

.flex-control-paging li a {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin: 0 3px;
  background-color: #b6b6b6 \9;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #b6b6b6;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #b6b6b6;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #b6b6b6;
}

.flex-control-paging li a.flex-active {
  background-color: #82d344;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#82d344), to(#51af34));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #82d344, #51af34);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #82d344, #51af34);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #82d344, #51af34);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #82d344, #51af34);
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}


/* Captions */

.flexslider .slides p {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 100px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #222222;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://designmodo.com/demo/responsiveslider/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-container" style="margin-bottom:50px;">
  <div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li class="">
        <img src="http://designmodo.com/demo/responsiveslider/img/slide1.jpg" />
      </li>

      <li>
        <img src="http://designmodo.com/demo/responsiveslider/img/slide2.jpg" />
      </li>

      <li>
        <img src="http://designmodo.com/demo/responsiveslider/img/slide3.jpg" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank for the answer but if i want to change all my image on slide to canvas when it load, what should i do

Comment: so you mean, you want to show all images to canvas or?

Comment: Yes, what i mean is all the image in the slide will now become canvas, dynamic draw canvas depend on number of image.
For example: if the slide have 4 image then draw 4 canvas